# How to completely remove dottrace

Tags: resharper, uninstallation, dottrace

Currently I have licenses for the following JetBrains products:

ReSharper 8.2.0.2160

Dotcover 2.7.1.238

I recently needed to use Dottrace, so installed the latest version from the JetBrains website. However I found this is incompatible with the other, earlier products, so uninstalled it.

Except it didn't uninstall properly. I still see dottrace menus, which still appear to function, and ReSharper is still broken. I have tried completely uninstalling and then re-installing Visual Studio (together with resharper and dotcover), yet this has still not improved anything. I still see Dottrace menus and ReSharper is still broken.

I've tried the JetBrains support forums (https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5536694#5536694), but they have not been helpful. Has anyone here experienced a similar issue, or have ideas as to how it can be resolved?

I'm starting to get desperate. Is there any way I can fix my development environment short of completely re-installing windows?

Answer (score 4):

The problem was solved by JetBrains support. In case anyone else has the same issue, all you need to do to solve it, is to delete the directory:

C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio[version_number]\Extensions\JetBrains

Comment: @Catartis Well, it is not located at that location

Comment: This is not entirely correct. I still have an executable named "JetBrains.ETW.Collector.Host.exe" in program files which runs with startup and CLRProfiler is not running anymore.

Comment: "JetBrains.ETW.Collector.Host.exe" is a service. Stop it and disable/remove it. Then you can also delete the file. This is what I did.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling first, and reinstalling Visual Studio from the installer.